# Why is the return type in my python code NoneType?

Tags: python, types, integer, binary-search, nonetype

I'm relatively new to Python and I'm working on a LeetCode problem and I created a binarySearch method and it should be returning an int.

```
class Solution(object):
def search(self, nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    nums.sort()
    
    index = self.binarySearch(nums, 0, len(nums) - 1, target)
    
    return index
    #binary search
def binarySearch(self, nums, l, r, target):
    
    if r >= l:
        mid = (r - l + 1) // 2
        if nums[mid] == target:
            return mid
        
        elif nums[mid] < target:
            self.binarySearch(nums, mid + 1, r, target)
        elif nums[mid] > target:
            self.binarySearch(nums, l, mid-1, target)
            
    
    else:
        return -1
```

So referring to my code above, the variable mid is of type int and I confirmed that by printing its type. However, when I call the function `index = self.binarySearch(nums, 0, len(nums) - 1, target)`, the index variable is a NoneType. Can someone please explain to be why index is a NoneType when the method returns an int?

Thanks!

Comment: your `elif` branches are not *returning* anything. Perhaps you forgot to use `return`?

Comment: There's a path in that code that doesn't do a return.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yup that was it thanks a ton! Such a silly mistake I didn't catch.